# FFmpeg Autogen and Unity C# to generate video from screenshots (FFmpeg.Autogen)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg

I've taken the `FFmpegHelper`, `VideoFrameConverter`, `H264VideoStreamEncoder` classes straight from the [FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/tree/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example), rolled my own `FFmpegBinariesHelper class` and `Size struct` and mangled the `EncodeImagesToH264` from Program.cs to look like the below code. I capture a bunch of frames into textures and feed them into `Encoder.EncodeImagesToH264`. It produces a file I'm calling `outputFileName.h264` just fine, no errors. I've changed `H264VideoStreamEncoder` a little based on ffmpeg's own c++ examples because they had a few things it seemed the C# example was missing but that hasn't made any difference.

The video is weird:

1. it only plays in VLC, is there another `AVPixelFormat` I should be using for the `destinationPixelFormat` so that anything can play?
2. VLC is unable to detect the video length or show current time
3. it plays back weird as if the first few seconds are all the same frame then starts playing what appears to be some of the frames I'd expect

```
    public static class Encoder
    {
        public static unsafe void EncodeImagesToH264(Texture2D[] images, int fps, string outputFileName)
        {
            FFmpegBinariesHelper.RegisterFFmpegBinaries();

            var fistFrameImage = images[0];
            outputFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(outputFileName, ".h264");
            var sourceSize = new Size(fistFrameImage.width, fistFrameImage.height);
            var sourcePixelFormat = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
            var destinationSize = sourceSize;
            var destinationPixelFormat = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

            try
            {
                using (var vfc = new VideoFrameConverter(
                    sourceSize,
                    sourcePixelFormat,
                    destinationSize,
                    destinationPixelFormat))
                {
                    using var fs = File.Open(outputFileName, FileMode.Create);
                    using var vse = new H264VideoStreamEncoder(fs, fps, destinationSize);
                    var frameNumber = 0;
                    foreach (var frameFile in images)
                    {
                        var bitmapData = GetBitmapData(frameFile);

                        //var pBitmapData = (byte*)NativeArrayUnsafeUtility
                        //    .GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks(bitmapData);

                        fixed (byte* pBitmapData = bitmapData)
                        {
                            var data = new byte_ptrArray8 { [0] = pBitmapData };
                            var linesize = new int_array8 { [0] = bitmapData.Length / sourceSize.Height };
                            var frame = new AVFrame
                            {
                                data = data,
                                linesize = linesize,
                                height = sourceSize.Height
                            };

                            var convertedFrame = vfc.Convert(frame);
                            convertedFrame.pts = frameNumber;

                            vse.Encode(convertedFrame);

                            Debug.Log($"frame: {frameNumber}");
                            frameNumber++;
                        }
                    }
                    byte[] endcode = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
                    fs.Write(endcode, 0, endcode.Length);
                }
                Debug.Log(outputFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogException(ex);
            }
        }

        private static byte[] GetBitmapData(Texture2D frameBitmap)
        {
            return frameBitmap.GetRawTextureData();
        }
    }

    public sealed unsafe class H264VideoStreamEncoder : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Size _frameSize;
        private readonly int _linesizeU;
        private readonly int _linesizeV;
        private readonly int _linesizeY;
        private readonly AVCodec* _pCodec;
        private readonly AVCodecContext* _pCodecContext;
        private readonly Stream _stream;
        private readonly int _uSize;
        private readonly int _ySize;

        public H264VideoStreamEncoder(Stream stream, int fps, Size frameSize)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _frameSize = frameSize;

            var codecId = AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
            _pCodec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_encoder(codecId);
            if (_pCodec == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Codec not found.");

            _pCodecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(_pCodec);
            _pCodecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
            _pCodecContext->width = frameSize.Width;
            _pCodecContext->height = frameSize.Height;
            _pCodecContext->time_base = new AVRational { num = 1, den = fps };
            _pCodecContext->gop_size = 10;
            _pCodecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
            _pCodecContext->pix_fmt = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

            if (codecId == AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
                ffmpeg.av_opt_set(_pCodecContext->priv_data, "preset", "veryslow", 0);

            ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(_pCodecContext, _pCodec, null).ThrowExceptionIfError();

            _linesizeY = frameSize.Width;
            _linesizeU = frameSize.Width / 2;
            _linesizeV = frameSize.Width / 2;

            _ySize = _linesizeY * frameSize.Height;
            _uSize = _linesizeU * frameSize.Height / 2;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ffmpeg.avcodec_close(_pCodecContext);
            ffmpeg.av_free(_pCodecContext);
        }

        public void Encode(AVFrame frame)
        {
            if (frame.format != (int)_pCodecContext->pix_fmt)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid pixel format.", nameof(frame));
            if (frame.width != _frameSize.Width)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid width.", nameof(frame));
            if (frame.height != _frameSize.Height)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid height.", nameof(frame));
            if (frame.linesize[0] < _linesizeY)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Y linesize.", nameof(frame));
            if (frame.linesize[1] < _linesizeU)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid U linesize.", nameof(frame));
            if (frame.linesize[2] < _linesizeV)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid V linesize.", nameof(frame));
            if (frame.data[1] - frame.data[0] < _ySize)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Y data size.", nameof(frame));
            if (frame.data[2] - frame.data[1] < _uSize)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid U data size.", nameof(frame));

            var pPacket = ffmpeg.av_packet_alloc();
            try
            {
                int error;
                do
                {
                    ffmpeg.avcodec_send_frame(_pCodecContext, &frame).ThrowExceptionIfError();
                    ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
                    error = ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_packet(_pCodecContext, pPacket);
                } while (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR(ffmpeg.EAGAIN));

                error.ThrowExceptionIfError();

                using var packetStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(pPacket->data, pPacket->size);
                packetStream.CopyTo(_stream);
            }
            finally
            {
                ffmpeg.av_packet_free(&pPacket);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use DirectShow instead of having to use low-level types directly in C#?  That or make a C++/CLI project

Comment: I'd like to use ffmpeg via FFmpeg.Autogen. Further, I ran the vanilla FFmpeg.Autogen.Example project and the `out.h264` file it produces has the same problems as the results I'm seeing from Unity. The video has a fairly decent lag spike before it starts to play in VLC, VLC is unable to display the video's length or current playback time.

Comment: Hmmm ok so sounds like the problem isn't with playback so much but rather with how it was encoded :/

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you know how to fix it?  thanks